# What is the best way to delete model but save record in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there any gem, that would give me this: I'd like to persist all the records inside my database on model destroy.

I've tried this way:

```
class Persist < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { where(removed: nil) }

    def destroy
        write_attribute :removed, Time.now
    end
end
```

I'm just wondering, is there any better way to do this? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:
https://github.com/radar/paranoia

For Rails 4, please use version 2 of Paranoia:

```
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.0'
```

and in your model:

```
class Persist < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [act a little paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid) to do that:

```
class Paranoiac < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
end
```

Comment: oh well, c'est la vie. you could make it work with rails 4, I think. People would appreciate your PR. :)

Comment: actually, paranoia looks like working stuff for me :)